# std::atomic_flag initialization result

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Is is really necessery to initialize `std::atomic_flag` in this way:

```
std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
```

In my opinion it should have same result:

```
std::atomic_flag flag;
flag.clear();
```

I have read all about this class from cppreference, but I am still not sure.

Comment: Is there some scenario/code which exhibits different behavior?

Comment: I do not know but I am asking about that in order to know what does the standard says about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT):

> This is the only way to initialize std::atomic_flag to a definite value: the value held after any other initialization is unspecified.